# Authorize an org failed in VS code

Tags: salesforcedx, authorization, sfdx-error

I am new to learning lightning web component. I have installed VS Code, the salesforce extension pack inside VS code, Salesforce CLI

I am trying to complete the Quick Start: Lightning Web Components module, I have created a project and when I use the command prompt to authorize an Org, I keep receiving this error message

> Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org

> 14:33:15.362 sfdx org:login:web --alias vscodeOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
> Warning: Ignoring extra certs from `null`, load failed: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory
> file:///C:/Program%20Files/sf/client/bin/run:12
> require('../dist/flags').preprocessCliFlags(process);
> ^
>
> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
> at file:///C:/Program%20Files/sf/client/bin/run:12:1
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
> at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
> at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
> at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)
>
> Node.js v20.10.0
> 14:33:15.911 sfdx org:login:web --alias vscodeOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
> ended with exit code 1

Please anyone help me out. Thanks

Comment: I am also working on the Quick Start: Lightning Web Components module and got the "Warning: Ignoring extra certs from null, load failed: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory" error. Originally, everything just hung and I was not able to Authorize the Org. When I rebooted (first time since the SF CLI install), that allowed me to go further and Authorize the Org but I still got the same load error above. Looks like I am missing some library install on my system? There is another more recent post with the same error: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414996/sfdx-a

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem in the installer in windows operating system.

I recommend you first uninstall the Salesforce CLI installed on your machine using windows installer. The instructions to uninstall are as [below](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm). Use the section under windows.

Next install the Salesforce CLI via the Node.js. All you have to do is ensure Node.js and NPM is installed.

Download Node.js and NPM using the [installer page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Ensure Node.js is installed using `node --version`

Ensure NPM is installed using `npm --version`

Install latest version of the Salesforce CLI using `npm install @salesforce/cli --global`

Verify that Salesforce CLI is installed via `sf --version`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the environment variable you added in 'Path' is not correct.
Find the location where you have sfdx installed, go inside the bin folder and copy paste this path in the path variable.

Comment: I copied the "SFDX" path (note that SFDX is the project name I created from the VSCode, and saved as a file in the system)... then placed in the path variable from environment variables. But it still didn't work

Comment: It should not be the project which you created. It should be the salesforce CLI bin file location.

Comment: Normally the installed location would be C:\Program Files\  check for folder sf or sfdx(depends on version) go inside and open 'bin' folder. copy this location and set it as the path. For me it looks like 'C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin'

Comment: Okay, It was already existing in the path as "C:\Program Files\sf\bin" but I still copied and added it to the path. it still didn't work

Comment: Error is saying its not able to find some system library. Could you retry installing sfdx cli and try once more?